# Datetime in class factor into two class date + time

Tags: r, datetime

I would like to convert my column (like below) in r automatically in class factor

```
Date.and.time..UTC.
2016-10-09 00:00:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:10:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:20:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:30:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:40:00+00:00

class(mdata$Date.and.time..UTC.)
[1] "factor"
```

into deux columns : Date (class date) + time (class time)

Is it possible?

The goal is to remove at each day the time between midnight and 6 am.

Comment: What have you tried? `as.Date` works fine on your column for converting to `Date` class. For `time` class, there is no `time` class built in to R, can you please specify what package's `time` class you would like to use?

Comment: Yes i'm tried as.date, as.POSIXlt, but the problem is when I'm doing that it's gives me NA value for all the column. I'm sorry I wouldn't told about class time but refer maybe for strptime.

Answer (score 0):

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = "Date.and.time..UTC.
2016-10-09 00:00:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:10:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:20:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:30:00+00:00
2016-10-09 00:40:00+00:00", header = T, sep = "\t")
```

`as.Date` and `as.POSIXct` work just fine:

```
df$date = as.Date(df$Date.and.time..UTC.)
df$datetime = as.POSIXct(df$Date.and.time..UTC.)
df
#         Date.and.time..UTC.       date            datetime
# 1 2016-10-09 00:00:00+00:00 2016-10-09 2016-10-09 00:00:00
# 2 2016-10-09 00:10:00+00:00 2016-10-09 2016-10-09 00:10:00
# 3 2016-10-09 00:20:00+00:00 2016-10-09 2016-10-09 00:20:00
# 4 2016-10-09 00:30:00+00:00 2016-10-09 2016-10-09 00:30:00
# 5 2016-10-09 00:40:00+00:00 2016-10-09 2016-10-09 00:40:00
```